# Updating the date portion of a javascript object without changing the time portion

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

What is the best way in JavaScript to set the date portion of a JavaScript date object without affecting the time portion?

Lets say you have a date like this
`Wed Oct 31 2012 10:15:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

And you want to update it to be November 1st without changing the time.

At first glance, you'd think this would work,

```
exampledate.setFullYear(2012);
exampledate.setMonth(10);
exampledate.setDate(1);
```

But the result is
`Sat Dec 01 2012 10:15:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

I think reason for this is that October has 31 days and November has just 30.  Since this obviously doesn't work right all the time.  What are my other options?  Will I have to create a new date object?

Comment: Are you talking about the conversion from EDT to EST? If so, keep in mind that on November 4th at 2am, countries using EDT switch to EST while magically receiving an extra hour.

Comment: Also, should you `setMonth` call be 11 and not 10? I see the final date as December.

Comment: That's the problem. Since the original date was 10/31/2012 and i'm setting the date to 11/31/2012, which isn't a real date, the second line is turning the date to december 1st.  The final line isn't doing anything.

Comment: Ah, I see your point now :) You may want to consider using a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @MichaelMior, no need for an external dependency, this can be done natively using `setFullYear(year,month,date)`

Comment: @zachelrath Absolutely for this case. But if you're doing a lot of date manipulation, it make things much nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript Date object setter methods often allow you to (optionally) set multiple date/time components all at once (in addition to the primary component), as appropriate for the situation --- this is what you want to do.

For your use case, the syntax for `setFullYear` is `setFullYear(year,month,day)`, so in addition to explicitly setting the year (which would cause the month and date to be implicitly updated based on your initial date), you could also explicitly set the month and day while you're at it. For instance:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(2020,10,3);
```

will return

```
Tue Nov 03 2020 13:10:34 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

See [the JavaScript setFullYear() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setfullyear.asp) for more details.

Because the time components of the Date object (e.g. hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) are not dependent on the date portions (year,month,date), your initial time components will be maintained. If you need to then update the time components, you can safely use `setHours()` or other methods as needed, because no implicit updates to the date components will occur.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

*First* set the date, then the month.