# Javascript Date() object with NULL Time

Tags: javascript, date, time, types

Is there a way to indicate only the date portion of a Date() object, without indicating the time?

e.g.

```
var d = Date();
d.setFullYear(2015, 0, 13);
d.toString();

"Tue Jan 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)"  // Wrong - I didn't set a time!
"Tue Jan 13 2015     NULL GMT-0500 (EST)"  // Expected Result
```

I want to be able to tell the difference between a user who only inputed the Date portion, vs one who *explicitly* inputed both a Date and a Time

Comment: Similar question but not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689023/updating-the-date-portion-of-a-javascript-object-without-changing-the-time-porti/13689218#13689218

Comment: "Wrong - I didn't set a time!" --- don't confuse data with its representation.

Comment: You'll never get `null` as that would be invalid, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to

Comment: `(new Date()).toDateString()` ?

Comment: You can format the date string yourself by extracting whatever fields you want via the Date API, or you could use a library like Moment.js or DateJS to do it. A Date object *always* has both date and time information.

Comment: Understood. I guess I could reword my question: Is there any way to separate the Date and the Time portion?

Comment: `d.split('00:00:00').shift();`

Comment: I want to be able to tell the difference between a user who only inputed the Date portion, vs one who explicitly inputed both a Date and a Time

Comment: "to separate the Date and the Time portion" --- to separate them from where? The `Date` type incorporates both by design.

Comment: "I want to be able to tell the difference between a user who only inputed the Date portion" --- and then finally you started explaining the **REAL PROBLEM**. How about you create a new type that uses `Date` as a data storage together with a flag like `hasTimePortion`? So like a custom type with 2 fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. A Javascript `Date` object always has a time. You can leave it at midnight and ignore it if you want, but it'll still be there. It's up to you how you interpret it.

If you want to be able to represent a null time, you could interpret midnight to mean that, though then you would have no way to represent times that actually *are* midnight. If you want to be able to have a null time and still represent every possible time you would need to have two variables.

You could have:

```
// Date with null time
var date = new Date(2015, 0, 13); // time component ignored
var time = null;

// Date with non-null time
var date = new Date(2015, 0, 13); // time component ignored
var time = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 9, 30); // date component ignored
```

Note in the second example the year, month and day in the `time` component are arbitrary and won't be used, but they still need to be there if you want to create a `Date` object.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the well-edited answer. 

Thought of another hackaround. As pointed out in Ken's answer, the Date() object has granularity to the millisecond, which my datepicker + timepicker doesn't use anyway. So I can exploit that to my advantage:

I can set the "pristine" default time to 1 millisecond past midnight, which I will treat as "NULL", and midnight to the millisecond would be treated as explicit midnight.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript Date objects are internally defined using number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.  Therefore you are stuck with the time part.

Try this code

```
var date = new Date(2015, 0, 13);
console.log(date.valueOf());
```

You'll get this output

```
1421125200000
```

Here is the standard definition...

[ECMAScript Language Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)  See page 165

From ECMA standard:

A Date object contains a Number indicating a particular instant in time to within a millisecond. Such a Number
is called a time value. A time value may also be NaN, indicating that the Date object does not represent a
specific instant of time.

Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC. In time values leap seconds
are ignored. It is assumed that there are exactly 86,400,000 milliseconds per day. ECMAScript Number values
can represent all integers from –9,007,199,254,740,992 to 9,007,199,254,740,992; this range suffices to
measure times to millisecond precision for any instant that is within approximately 285,616 years, either
forward or backward, from 01 January, 1970 UTC.

The actual range of times supported by ECMAScript Date objects is slightly smaller: exactly –100,000,000
days to 100,000,000 days measured relative to midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970 UTC. This gives
a range of 8,640,000,000,000,000 milliseconds to either side of 01 January, 1970 UTC.
The exact moment of midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970 UTC is represented by the value +0

Comment: +1 Thanks for pulling out the spec. The milliseconds I did not realize - this actually gives me an idea, will add my own answer

Answer (score 2):

Dates are objects. As such, you can add properties to them as needed:

```
var date_only = new Date("2015-03-04");
date_only.time_is_meaningful = false;

var date_with_time = new Date("2015-03-04T10:47");
date_with_time.time_is_meaningful = true;
```

This is simpler and cleaner than your millisecond hack, and more
convenient than having two separate variables. You could then, if you
wish, subclass Date with a custom `toString` that checks the
`time_is_meaningful` property and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the time information from a Date.
If you want to have both informations independently, use a Date for the date and ignore the time (e.g. ensure it's always exactly midnight for instance), and use another field to hold the time (it could be a Date where you ignore the date but not the time, or it could be one input text with formatted time, or several input texts with hour, minute, etc).
The UI representation is up to you.

Comment: that's pretty much what Andrew suggested as well a minute earlier.